# crash in MultipartEntityBuilder build function

Tags: android, apache-httpcomponents

My app is crashing at MultipartEntityBuilder.build().

I am getting the following error if i add

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'

in my build.gradle

My code:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
builder = builder.addPart("file", contentPart);
builder = builder.addPart("childId", new StringBody("1235342"));
builder = builder.addTextBody("bodyText", "userName");
HttpEntity entity = null;
try {
         entity = builder.build();   << crash here
} catch (Exception e) {
         Log.i("satisfy", e.getMessage());
     }
```

crash :

Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' exception.

## build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.svaast"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile files('libs/childDetailsApi-v1-1.21.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'


    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    //compile files('libs/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

files in libs folder:
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar

## update:

After a lot of google searching, i found that i was missing httpmime library, but when i add httpmime library, gradle sync fails saying:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart$1.class

Any advice, how can i move ahead, i am stuck here for last 2 days.
Any help would be grateful

## Another update:

I modified my build. gradle to following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.svaast"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile files('libs/childDetailsApi-v1-1.21.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'

    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'

    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    //compile files('libs/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

while gradle sync is successful, running application, get the following error:

```
  Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
  :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :app:checkDebugManifest
  :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:appengineDownloadSdk
  :backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:appengineEndpointsExpandClientLibs UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:compileEndpointsSrcJava UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:processEndpointsSrcResources UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:endpointsSrcClasses UP-TO-DATE
  :backend:_appengineEndpointsAndroidArtifact UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComDaimajiaSliderLibrary115Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComGithubLechoHellochartsLibrary158Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-   DATE
  :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
  :app:prepareDebugDependencies
  :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
  :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
  :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
  :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
  :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
  :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
  :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
  :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
  :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
  :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

**Note:** Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
**:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.class**
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 6.321 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

## Error in android monitor:

```
03-11 17:05:49.819 1977-3150/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:268)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.au.run(SourceFile:140)
03-11 17:05:49.899 1287-1299/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
03-11 17:05:49.902 1287-1849/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
03-11 17:05:49.905 1977-3151/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Uploader:  no longer exists, so no auth token.
03-11 17:14:40.980 1287-1303/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
03-11 17:14:40.981 1287-1303/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49) 
at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002) 
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
03-11 17:14:40.981 1287-1303/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71) 
at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031) 
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: have you tried multidexing ??

Comment: Hi @BajiraoShinde

multiDexEnabled true is set in build.gradle

But still no success at time of running the code

Comment: have you extended your application class with it and what is contentpart  ??

Comment: Could you please guide me for the same???

Comment: see my answer bellow...hope it helps.